# ICMPv6 send Multicast Listener Report Message and Neighbor Solicitation

Tags: debian, ipv6, redundancy

I am configuring ucarp on two on my pc router ie master and slave. Master is turned off and then turned on, recorded in tshark slave application there is icmpv6 multicast listener report message and neighbor solicitation. But I do not configure ipv6 in ucarp (using common address redundancy protocol).

Is this an additional protocol that appears when the new master router is enabled?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "you did not configure IPv6": The Linux kernel handles link-local IPv6 address configuration automatically even if you didn't explicitely configure it, unless you remove the necessary modules or turn it off explicitely.